# Specific date format string not being displayed in Edit mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following Display Attribute

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
```

This renders both correctly in my Index Page as well as my Edit pages

Index.cshtml (list of items)

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
```

Edit.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

However the date format needs to be  in the format dd/MMM/yyyy e.g. 20/Oct/2015, 
so I change the display attribute to

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
```

In my Index.cshtml is displayed correctly as 20/Oct/2015.

The problem is when I open it in Edit.cshtml, it doesn't load the property value that gets passed to the ViewModel but displays the value as as

[image]

1. Why does {0:yyyy-MM-dd} work but not "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}?
2. How to make it work?

Comment: Because your generating the browsers `datepicker` which requires the date to be in ISO (yyyy-MM-dd) format (not this only works in Chrome and will generate a normal textbox in IE & FireFox

Comment: Rather that `EditorFor()` use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })` and keep the  `DataFormatString` for use by `DisplayFor()`